# How to sort XML feed using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am new this parsing xml feeds; so I have a piece of code that I have been working on that extracts the data from the xml file. Now I want be able to sort the array by the publish date pubdate. I have not found any examples that can anyone help me.

I used sort() which puts it in some random order.

```
$xml_headline_key = "*ARRAY*CATCHUP*PROGRAMMENAME";
$xml_link_key = "*ARRAY*CATCHUP*ITEMURL";
$xml_description_key = "*ARRAY*CATCHUP*SHORTSYNOPSIS";
$xml_publish_key = "*ARRAY*CATCHUP*ORIGINALAIRINGDATE";
$story_array = array();
$counter = 0;
class xml_story{
 var $headline, $description, $link, $pubdate;
}
function contents($parser, $data){
 global $current_tag, $xml_headline_key, $xml_link_key, $xml_description_key, $counter, $story_array, $xml_link_key, $xml_publish_key;
 switch($current_tag){
  case $xml_headline_key:
   $story_array[$counter] = new xml_story();
   $story_array[$counter]->headline = $data;
   break;
  case $xml_link_key:
   $story_array[$counter]->link = $data;
  break;
  case $xml_description_key:
   $story_array[$counter]->description = $data;
   $counter++;
   break;
  case $xml_publish_key:
   $story_array[$counter]->pubdate = $data;
  break;
  }
}

$corrie_counter = 0;
sort($story_array);
$dateformat = "D j M, g:ia";

for($x=0;$x<count($story_array);$x++){
 if($story_array[$x]->headline == "Coronation Street"){
 if($corrie_counter != 4){
 echo "<li><span class=\"bold\">". date($dateformat, strtotime($story_array[$x]->pubdate)) . "</span>\n";
echo "\t<span class=\"text\">" . trunc($story_array[$x]->description,30, " ") . "</span>\n";
```

echo "\t";
  $corrie_counter++;
  } 
 }
}

Comment: If you want to save some time, I would highly recommend the magpie rss parser. http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @shane this does look like rss but xml !== rss

Answer (score 2):

You can use [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), and inside *sortByPubdate* define the way the two *pubdates* should be compared.

```
uasort($story_array, 'sortByPubdate');
// Sort function
function sortByPubdate($a, $b) {
    if ($a->pubdate == $b->pubdate) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->pubdate < $b->pubdate) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it didn't work the content is the same as before, actually the sort(); actually sorted more than the uasort. Is there something else I need to add with uasort am I missing something???? Oh yeah I included it just above the for loop.

Comment: Is possible the $story_array is already sorted by date? Just try to order it by a different field (maybe the headline). Also take a look to the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php